# Can a folder browser be included in a Windows 7 gadget?

Tags: javascript, html, windows, windows-desktop-gadgets

I'm developing a windows gadget for windows 7 and I was wondering if there's a way to add a folder browser to it.

I'm aware that's not an input type in HTML, and therefore, coding must be done (I already achieved that) but I would like to know if there's a way to embed some c# code in the gadget or any other solution you guys can think of.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just want to make sure, you are aware that Windows 7 Gadgets are [deprecated and considered a security risk right](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/windows-7-gadgets/e0940f43-8324-4043-9465-fb34298806d0)?  If this is a new project, you may want to consider alternatives.

Comment: I am now aware of that (thanks btw) but it doesn't matter. It has to be that way, I cannot discuss why though.